# How to get back the focus on popup, after losing it in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, popup

I have a main window, If I click a certain button, I have a popUp window, that pops up with few different component (input, button, dropdownlist etc) on it. Everything works fine, until I lose focus by simply clicking outside. And if I want to come back, I click back on Popup, but it can't be active again, and for that to be active, I have to click on the Main window, or to click on the appIcon on the taskBar.

Have you guys ever had such problem?

And How to resolve it?

Thank you!

Comment: My problem seems to be simular to [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290504/wpf-popup-not-causing-application-to-be-focused-when-clicked-on)

Comment: But I dont get the solution. He ended up solving the problem by Using somethig like  **Preview... mouse events**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [PreviewMouseDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewmousedown(v=vs.110).aspx) event. I have tested it and it does recover lost focus.

```
private void Popup_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    this.Focus();
}
```

Comment: but still did not understand the difference btw `MouseDown` and `PreviewMouseDowm`

Comment: `MouseDown` event is raised by the control which you have clicked on. If you click on the TextBlock, which is inside of Popup, then `MouseDown` will be raised by that TextBlock only. If you click directly on Popup control, then `MouseDown` will be rised by Popup only. So if you want to handle both cases, then you should implement `TextBlock_MouseDown` and `Popup_MouseDown` handlers. `PreviewMouseDown` event is raised for the control you have clicked on and for all underlying controls. So it is enough to handle `PreviewMouseDown` only once for the top parent control - Popup.

Comment: Damnn, that was it. I got it at once. BOOM!
Cuz I had been looking for an explication, found few, but they were not clear enough. They were talking about tunnels, bubbles and stuff ) Спасибо товарищ Кедров!